# In Flutter, how do I check that an image returns from Image Picker is valid?

Tags: flutter, image, validation, picker

I'm using the following code to select and load an image. Is there any way to validate if the image returned is valid? For example, users pick up video files instead of image files in which case an exception should be raised.The issue is that the Exception block never gets called even if the return image is invalid.

```
  Future<Image?> imgFromGallery(
          double cWidth, double cHeight ) async {
        final picker = ImagePicker();
        final XFile? pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(
            source: ImageSource.gallery,
            maxWidth: cHeight,
            maxHeight: cHeight,
            imageQuality: 100);
    
        if (pickedImage == null)  return Future.value();
    
        try {
          Image? img = Image.file(File(pickedImage.path));
         
          if (img == null) //this won't work, always false
 return Future.value();
          
          return img;
        } catch (e) {
```

return null; //this will never get called
print(e);
}

```
        return Future.value();
      }
```

Comment: I see that always works bro

Comment: where is the open bracket? doesn't it have to be `if(img == null) { //something here}`

Comment: The code is correct and it always works. My question is how do I know when a user picks up a wrong type of file, such as text or pdf file instead of an image file? In that case, I need to show users that the file or image type is not supported via a dialog.

Comment: library is facilitated that you can see only images from gallery .it is not display unsupported file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if image file exists by simply reading it as a file and check its existence using image.isNotEmpty.

```
Future<Image?> imgFromGallery(double cWidth, double cHeight) async {
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  final XFile? pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,
    maxWidth: cHeight,
    maxHeight: cHeight,
    imageQuality: 100,
  );
  if (pickedImage == null) return null;
  try {
    final file = File(pickedImage.path);
    final image = await file.readAsBytes();
    // Perform image validation
    if (image.isNotEmpty) {
      final img = Image.memory(image);
      return img;
    } else {
      // Invalid image file
      return null;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I don't think that this will work if a user chooses a PDF file or a text file instead of an image file. In that case, the file is not empty but an exception will be raised.

Comment: I am not sure if user can select PDF or other type of files using that ImagePicker

Comment: You are correct. Users can select video files not PDF when you really want them to select image files. In that case, Flutter will throw an exception which is not catchable by end user app and the app will crash.  The only solution that I can think of is to check file name extension but that's not the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is way you can limiting your pickup type.

```
final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
// Pick an image.
final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
// Capture a photo.
final XFile? photo = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
// Pick a video.
final XFile? galleryVideo =
    await picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
// Capture a video.
final XFile? cameraVideo = await picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera);
// Pick multiple images.
final List<XFile> images = await picker.pickMultiImage();
```

For more refer library document.-> https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using `source: ImageSource.gallery` in which case, a user can pick a video file instead of an image file. If that happens, currently there is no way to detect that. The exception is thrown by  Flutter `D/skia    (28235): --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'`.  The exception is not catchable by an user's app.